# Error on startup

Tags: startup, 23.10

When I start my computer, the motherboard screen shows, and then an error like this:

```
nuke: can't remove `/dev`: Directory not empty
```

What does this mean? Can it be fixed?

*Note: After that Ubuntu starts as normal*

Comment: That is from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/udev` cleaning up while setting up the mounts. If it's not causing problems, just ignore it. If I have to guess, it's because you have some hardware that's slow to start and coincidentally loaded while it was doing that.

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel T!